# FULL JOIN при использовании Entity Framework Core 2

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Есть 3 таблицы (2 с данными, 3я для связи многие ко многим).

Нужно выбрать все данные по этим таблицам.

Вот так выглядит нужный мне запрос

```
SELECT lt."id" lt_id, lt."name" lt_name, rt."id" rt_id, rt."name" rt_name FROM "middle_table" mt
FULL JOIN "left_table" lt ON lt."id" = mt."lt_id"
FULL JOIN "right_table" rt ON rt."id" = mt."rt_id";
```

Как я могу состряпать LINQ для этого запроса для использования с EF Core?

**UPD:**

Я попробовал через SQL это провернуть

```
ctx.MiddleTable.FromSql(...)
```

Не вышло. Получаю column is null, потому что таблица для связи имеет композитный ключ из идентификаторов левой и правой таблиц. А если я добавляю после FromSql()

```
.Select(x => new MiddleTable { LeftTable = x.LeftTable, RightTable = x.RightTable})
```

то запрос меняется на обычный JOIN и я получаю только те записи, которые реально присутствуют в таблице MiddleTable.

Comment: LINQ не знает про FULL OUTER JOIN, если верить документации... только в обход. См. напр. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5491381/10138734

Comment: Как вариант, если вы не завязаны жестко на EF, можно попробовать ORM linq2db. Она поддерживает весь набор джойнов: [Join Operators](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/wiki/Join-Operators)

Comment: @Akina в обход не пойдет. Нужна фильтрация, сортировка, пагинация...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov завязаны

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил на уровне БД.

Создал VIEW с FULL JOIN связкой.

На уровне ORM понадобилась новая модель. Миграцию сделал SQL'ем.
В контексте определил новую сущность как DbQuery.